# Count number of rows with a specific MONTH in the date of a specific cell and a Boolean condition in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

Let's say I have a number of dates and whether they occupy full or half a day:

```
   DATE  |         WHAT        | HALF?
...
2021-4-1 | Something Something | false
2021-4-2 | Something Something | false
2021-4-5 | Something Something | false
2021-4-19| Something Something | true
2021-5-13| Something Something | false
2021-5-24| Something Something | false
2021-9-13| Something Something | true
...
```

I now want for each month the amount of half-days occupied in that list.
(e.g. for `April` that should be `1` in the examples above, for `May` that should be `0`)

I.e. in pseudocode, I'm looking for something like

```
=COUNTIF(A8:A, `MOTH of row = MONTH(E2)` AND `half of row = true`)
```

where `E2`, in this case, is e.g. `January` stored as a date.

And `A8:A` contains the dates of the above table (i.e. `B8:B` contains the `WHAT` and `C8:C` contains the `HALF?`).

Answer (score 0):

To get results by year and month, try the following in `E1`

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({TEXT(A1:A,"yyyy-mmm"),B1:C}), 
           "select Col1, count(Col3) 
            where Col3=TRUE 
            group by Col1 
            label count(Col3) 'Half/month' ",1)
```

**OR**
To get results by just month, try the following in `G1`

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({TEXT(A1:A,"mmm"),B1:C}), 
           "select Col1, count(Col3) 
            where Col3=TRUE 
            group by Col1 
            label count(Col3) 'Half/month' ",1)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)